# python-memcache does not load/store anything

Tags: python, caching, memcached

So I tried out memcache. Did "apt-get install python-memcache" on my Ubuntu, and then:

```
>>> import memcache
>>> s = memcache.Client(["127.0.0.1:11211"])
>>> s.set("mykey", "myvalue")
0
>>> myvar = s.get("mykey")
>>> print(myvar)
None
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have memcached service running. Here's how it looks when the service is up:

```
>>> s = memcache.Client(["127.0.0.1:11211"])
>>> s.set("mykey", "myvalue")
True
>>> myvar = s.get("mykey")
>>> print(myvar)
myvalue
```

Here's how you can check if it is running or not:

```
$ service memcached status
 * memcached is running
```

Comment: Okay, it was rather silly: I didn't see that I don't have a memcache-service INSTALLED at all, so I manually had to `apt-get install memcached`. Now your service commands work, as well as the above code. :)

Am I right with that: python-memcache uses the same commands (relating to syntax) as the memcached-module itself? Because I can't seem to find any extra Documentation to python-memcache apart from pythons build-in help system.